# How to initialize a huge array in java?

Tags: java

I need to write a java program where I have to initialize 9000 int values. How can I initialize that static array?

I have values like 20954,70955,20156,3057,9058,20759,18960,961 and so on (9000 numbers).... I want initialize these numbers to the array.

Similarly I have 8 arrays.

I can save in text file and can read while execution. But for parsing it is taking time Suggest please.

Comment: 9000 `int`s isn't huge.

Comment: So where do you get the values from? I mean, do you have them right now written on a paper or so?

Comment: I suggest reading the [FAQ]

Comment: I have values like 20954,20955,20956,20957,20958,20959,20960,20961 and so on....   And also similiar like I have seven more arrays. When I put this in constructor it shows byte limits exceed.

Comment: If an int number is bigger than 65535 you've to use LONG. Not int.....

Comment: You need to load the int values from an external file, you cannot construct large arrays in Java code. BTW 9000 ints will fit in your L2 cache.

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] array= new int[9000];
Random random = new Random();

for (int i =0; i< array.length; i++)
{
     array[i] = random.nextInt(9000)+1;
}
```

Comment: -1 : OP asked how to fill array. Is there a need to use Random?

Comment: Okay- it may be good example (removing negatve vote)

Comment: People can answer different ways...thnx...@Jayan..

Comment: upvote for different perspectitve

Answer (score 2):

You can good initializing just as a normal array of `int` of size `9000`.

```
int[] numbers = new int[9000];
```

Now, to load the values into the array, you can use looping mechanism.

```
for(int i = 0; i< numbers.length; i++) {
    number[i] = // your value
}
```

**But still the question is, how are you getting the so called 9000 integers?**

If you're getting values from a comma-separated `String` like `"2,5,23,523,"`, you can do.

```
// String input = "2,5,23,523"; // 9000 integers
String[] strArray = input.split(",");
int[] numbers = new int[strArray.length];
for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
}
```

Or,

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 5, 23, 323, 2342, 1351 }; // 9000 numbers
```

Comment: Sorry, If I parse the string it will take more time for execution. Also similiar like this I have 8 arrays. Values are static only.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar You can update your question. Based upon your comment in question, you have values like `20954,20955,20956,20957,20958,20959,20960,20961` which are sequential for which you can easily use looping logic. As you mentioned, you've 7 more of such arrays, you can use multiple loops to populate one array of integers i.e `numbers`. Beware of integer limit i.e `65535`, use `long` then. Update your question and let me know, I'll follow along. Hoping, you got what you want.

Comment: The values I put here are in sequence, but not all.

Comment: @Rajesh Then, why don't you just initialize array as `int[] numbers = { 13432,3244, 31413, ... }`. If you can't do that, `String` manipulation is your way. How else do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Intialize
int[] integers = new int[9000];

// Populate with some random integers
for(int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++){
    integers[i] = new Random().nextInt();
}

// Write the values in a file
PrintWriter pr = null;

try {
    pr = new PrintWriter("outputFile.txt");    

    for (int i=0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        pr.println(integers[i]);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    // TODO Handle appropriately

} finally {

     if(pr != null)
        pr.close();

}
```

Comment: I have values like 20954,20955,20956,20957,20958,20959,20960,20961 and so on.... I want initialize these numbers to the array. Similiarly I have 8 arrays.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar You have to do something like integers[index] = 20954; where index is the position at array. So, if you want first item in array to contain 20960, you would do integers[0] = 20960; Remember array starts with index 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] manyIntegers= new int[9000];
```

Comment: I guess you mean int[] not Int

Comment: I have values like 20954,20955,20956,20957,20958,20959,20960,20961 and so on.... And also similiar like I have seven more arrays. When I put this in constructor it shows byte limits exceed.

Comment: If an int number is bigger than 65535 you've to use LONG. Not int.....

Comment: I am getting this error, Not int memory error. Too many constants, the constant pool for config would exceed 65536 entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] manyIntegers= new int[9000];

for(int i = 0; i < manyIntegers.length; i++){
    manyIntegers[i] = YOUR_VALUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have 9000 integers that cannot be generated/calculated somehow, I think you should do it the good old way:

```
static int[] myValues = new int[] {
    3, 5, 2, 7, 100, 8, 15, 7, 5645, 134, // the first 10 ints
    // 899 more lines
}
```

That's as simple as writing them to a separate text file but without any need to load/parse something.

As the maximum number of static initializer code is 65535 bytes, there should be no other `static` fields in the same class. I could manage to initialize an `int` array of length 9516 that way but not more.

Comment: I an getting "exceeding the 65535 bytes limit" error

Comment: I think, you're declaring a local variable inside a method. That doesn't work because of the limit. Use a static variable instead!

Comment: I was partly wrong. There is also a 65535 bytes limit on static initializer code. But 9000 ints are doable. I've edited my answer to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

And of course there's `Arrays.fill`

```
int[] array = new int[9000];
// All of them.
Arrays.fill(a,2);
// Just some of them.
Arrays.fill(a,100,200,6);
```

Comment: Will it run under java 1.4

Comment: @Rajesh - [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int[],%20int%29) suggests `Arrays` existed in Java 1.2. I cannot find any reference to `fill` arriving later.

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize array with ArrayList. For example `ArrayList a = new ArrayList();`. Of course, you must include `import java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: I am going to execute under low version of java (1.4). There ArrayList will not work